# Cannot add custom claims to User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my `ASPNET MVC 5` application i have this `authentication` method on `UserController`:

```
 private void Autenticar(UserDTO user, bool keepLoged= false)
    {
        var claims = user.Claims.Select(p => new Claim(p.Name, p.Value));
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = keepLoged}, identity);
    }
```

I call this method on the `Login` Action, the UserDTO object has a Claim list with 6 claims. But when i check it after this action execute, those 6 claims arent there.

What im doing wrong?